# Is there an archive file format that supports being split in multiple parts and can be unpacked natively on MS Windows?

Tags: windows, web-applications, archive, file-format

Some archive file formats, e.g. ZIP (see Section 8 in https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), support being split into multiple parts of a limited size. ZIP files can be opened natively on recent versions of Microsoft Windows, but it seems that Windows cannot open split ZIP files natively, only with special tools like 7-Zip. I would like to use this "split archive" functionality in a web app that I'm writing in which the created archives should be opened by a large audience of "average" computer users, so my question is: Is there an archive file format (like ZIP) that supports being split in multiple parts and can be unpacked without installing additional software on recent versions of Microsoft Windows? And ideally on other widely used operating systems as well.

*Background:* My final goal is to export a directory structure that is split over multiple web servers to a single local directory tree. My current idea is to have each web server produce one part of the split archive, provide all of them as some sort of Javascript multi-file download and then have one archive (in multiple parts) on the user's computer that just needs to be unpacked. An alternative idea for this final goal was to use Javascript's File System Access API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API), but it is not supported on Firefox, which is a showstopper.

Comment: If you only target Windows, why not just provide an SFX? If running any EXE is unwanted, then just provider regular ZIPs, as long as you extract them to the same folders you still have the same result. CAB file is natively supported on Windows and does support split files, but I'm not sure if other OS even support it.

Comment: @Martheen Most people can become _very_ suspicious when downloading an "archive" which reveals to be an executable... Me first. If I really need it, I won't launch it before sending it to every AV program I can get, and if I don't **need** it, it will go to trash bin directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CAB` archives meet this purpose a bit (see [this library's page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15397/Cabinet-File-CAB-Compression-and-Extraction) for example, it says that through it, archives can even be extracted directly from a HTTP(S)/FTP server). Since the library relies on .NET, it could even be used on Linux through Mono/Wine, which is a crucial part if your servers aren't running Windows... Because archive must be created on server, right?.

Your major problem is more that a split archive can't be created in parallel on multiple servers, at least because of LZx's dictionnary. Each server should create the whole set of archives and send only the ones it should send, and you don't have **ANY** guarantee that all these archives' sets would be identical on each server.

Best way is probably to create the whole archive on **ONE** server, then distribute each part (or the whole splitted archive...) on your various servers, through a replication-like interface.

Otherwise, you can also make individual archives that contains only a subset of the directory tree (you'll have to partition the files across servers), but it won't meet your requirements since it would be a collection of individual archives, and not a big splitted archive.

Some precisions may be required:

- Do you absolutely need a system without any client besides the browser? Or can you use other protocols, as long as they natively exist on Windows (like FTP / SSH client that are now provided by default)?
- What is the real purpose behind this request? Distribute load across all servers? Or to avoid too big single file downloads (i.e. a 30 GB archive) in case of transfer failure? Or both?
- In case of a file size problem, why don't rely on resuming download?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the CAB format. Regarding the parallel creation problem: At least for ZIP I suppose parallel creation could work, because LZx is applied only to single files in the archive (unlike, e.g., tar.gz). For your questions: (1) I want "ease of use" for average computer users, so everything that works easily on plain Windows and can also be made to work on other platforms is OK. (2) The reason for distribution is privacy, one server should not be aware of the data on the others. So central creation is not possible.

Comment: @TobiasB. OK. Can you use a light standalone client, and not _only_ web browser? It can even be a program installed once for all who is only present in tray bar... And in this case, you could set up a FTP (FTP/TLS or SFTP) to get the job done, in background task, exactly like you would synchronize any usual cloud to your local system...

Comment: I would rather not use a stand-alone client. Regarding your original answer: I now tried the CAB format. Its feature set looked pretty good, and it works like a charm in 7-Zip, but the native Windows archive viewer seems not to be able to show the directory structure inside of a CAB :( So it looks like I have to compromise somewhere. I'll accept your answer anyway, because I think it's the closest I can get.